# Changing Chromebook Connection Settings Programmatically

Tags: linux, network-programming, google-chrome-os, chromebook

I want to programmatically change a ChromeBook connection settings (Configuring a wifi connection options such as protocol etc').
Looked everywhere and i can get an API (Java or any other high level language will be great) to do this.
Is anyone aware of such an API?